# Increasing page load time

Tags: javascript, code-organization, load-time

I have a javascript source code file which is about 32kb, and has javascript code arranged in modules.
I was wondering if it would increase page load time if i put each module into a separate file as managing the current code of over 2000 lines is quite tedious and some times confusing

Comment: The file access might slow the loading time a little, yes. You could split the code into several files and use a packager to merge and minify it for production use. The CKEditor does this when deploying the script from the development environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, yes and no. If you have a `<script>` tag pointing to each module file, then yes it will slow down the page due to the increased number of network calls to those files. The real answer is that's the way you should CODE it, but that's not the way you should serve it up to your user.

I recommend a tool called Minify, which will combine and minify all your JS files so you only need one `<script src="/min/f=mod1.js,mod2.js,mod3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` tag

You can also manage "groups" of files, which are simply PHP arrays with an associative key you reference in the script src. For example:

```
'module_js' => array(
            '//js/module1.js',
            '//js/module2.js',
            '//js/module3.js'
            )
```

Then your script tag would look like:

```
<script src="/min/g=module_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After Minify comines and minifies your code, it will cache it on your server so subsequent requests will hit the cache file so the PHP won't need to process.

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: the modules also have some jQuery plugins as dependicies

Comment: Thats perfectly fine, just make a group for all your JQuery plugins, and reference that group first: `<script src="/min/g=jquery_plugins,module_js" ...`